# How can i make hover effect on image with caption

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

so im having little bit of strugle making this work.

So basicly what i am trying to make is image with caption under it and when you hover over image it gets greenish color with transparency and a plus sign on it.

What ive tried so far is to make `<div class=parent>` and inside of `<div class=parent>` i would have `<img>` and another `<div class="overlay">`

**HTML**

```
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="parent">
        <img src="img/showcase.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery .overlay {
background: rgba(0, 188, 156, 0);
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
} /* this div overlay will be greenish transparent color over an image when image is hovered */

.gallery .parent {
 margin-top: 40px; 
} /* this is just some spacing when images go one under another */

.gallery .parent:hover .overlay {
background: rgba(0, 188, 156, 0.8); 
}

.gallery .parent:hover .fa-plus {
color: white; 
}

.gallery .fa-plus {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
font-size: 1.75em; 
}
```

**so this works perfectly fine.**

[image]

**But when i put caption in my HTML.**

```
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="parent">
       <img src="img/showcase.jpg">
       <div class="overlay">
         <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="caption">
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h5>
        <h6>lorem</h6>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

`<div class="overlay">` stretches all the way down

[image]

im running out of ideas how to make this possible especially because i need it to be responsive, images are changing widths and heights based on the resolution so i can put `<div class="overlay>` `height` on 80% or 90%

EG on medium devices.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the image inside its own container where you can add the overlay:

```css
.img-container {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}
.img-container img {
 display:block;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 188, 156, 0);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.gallery .parent {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.gallery .img-container:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 188, 156, 0.8);
}

.gallery .img-container:hover .fa-plus {
  color: white;
}

.gallery .fa-plus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/ ">
          <div class="overlay ">
            <i class="fas fa-plus ">+</i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption ">
          <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h5>
          <h6>lorem</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```